# Firefox focus() sets the focus and blurs immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, focus, onblur

I have a `<span class="numbers">` and this code for on Click, it creates a new `<input class="number_input">` field and sets the focus on it:

```
            $('body').on('click','.numbers', function () {
                oldNumbersValue = $(this).html();
                var input = $('<input />', {'style':'font-size:30pt','type': 'number','class':'number_input', 'name': 'aname', 'value': oldNumbersValue});
                $(this).parent().append(input);
                input.focus();
            });
```

When the field loses the focus, it will be removed:

```
 $('body').on('blur', '.number_input',function () {
// do something
 $(this).remove();
});
```

This works in Chrome but not in Firefox! In Firefox it creates the field, sets the focus on it and loses it immediately!

Any solutions?

**edit:**

working in chorme/not working in ff fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v8hmpgv2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that (for a reason I'm not 100% sure of), Firefox is triggering the `blur` event on `.number_input` after the element has been appended to the document, but before your `focus()` actually calls.

You can see this happening in Firefox with this [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3kaxLos4/2/) - note the order of the messages indicating when focus is set and lost on `.number_input`.

One way you could modify the code is to not use event delegation, and rather attach the `blur` handler directly to `.number_input`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.numbers', function (e) {
    oldNumbersValue = $(this).text();
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'style': 'font-size:30pt',
        'type': 'number',
        'class': 'number_input',
        'name': 'aname',
        'value': oldNumbersValue
    });
    $(this).parent().append(input);

    input.focus();
    input.blur(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kaxLos4/4/) to demonstrate. (Don't worry about any potential memory leakage due to constantly adding new event handlers - the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) indicate that `.remove()` should erase those each time.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.